# Apple "Strength" Commercial featuring Fitness Apps

Tags: ios, applications

Does anyone know fitness app featured where the guy is doing step-ups on a park bench followed by push-ups?

Answer (score 2):

According to Apple's webpage for the video, [Strength](http://www.apple.com/iphone-5s/powerful/#video-strength), it is [Seven Minute Workout](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/johnson-johnson-official-7/id784797900?mt=8)